# Static class as resource for xaml in wpf

Tags: wpf, mvvm, static

I try to use a static class as ResourceDirectory with StaticResources but it dont works.

Class:

```
  static class GlobalDefinitions
    {
        public const string Parameter = "Parameter";
    }
```

View:

```
xmlns:global="clr-namespace:Project.Global"

 <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Source={global:GlobalDefinitions,Path=Parameter}"/>
```

Does anyone know why?

I try to use a static class as ResourceDirectory with StaticResources but it dont works.

Comment: You are apparently not at all using a ResourceDirectory and hence also no StaticResource extension. What you are trying to do is to use a static class member as the source of a Binding.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`x:Static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/xaml-services/xstatic-markup-extension) markup extension:

```
<DataGridTextColumn
    Header="{Binding Source={x:Static global:GlobalDefinitions.Parameter}}"/>
```

Answer (score -2):

I will typically declare my class as a resource...

Given a class:

```
public class MyClass
{
  // 
}
```

Declare the resource (this is how it would look in App.xaml):

```
<Application.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
      <myNamespace:MyClass x:Key="MyClass" />
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then you can use it as a binding source e.g.:

```
<Window 
    DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyCLass}}"
    >
</Window>
```

WPF will create an instance of the class as needed to resolve the binding. For this approach to work, the class must have a parameterless constructor.

The class "Locator" pattern works this way; you could have underlying static members, but they would need to be wrapped by instance members.

Comment: This is not a static class, the very first thing you posted here was an instanced class definition.  This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Tarazed True but per my edit, you can have instance members wrap around statics